# How to set backgroundcolor of NSTableHeader properly?

Tags: swift, cocoa, subclass, background-color, nstableview

I spend the last day searching the internet for a way how to set the backgroundcolor of a NSTableHeaderCell. All I achieved was this:

```
func tableView(_ numberTableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

        if tableColumn!.identifier == "description" {

            let cell = NSTableHeaderCell()
            cell.title = "Header Title"
            cell.backgroundColor = NSColor.red
            cell.drawsBackground = true
            cell.isBordered = false
            cell.font = NSFont(name: "System", size: 13)
            tableColumn!.headerCell = cell
        }
        return nil
    }
```

The result Looks like this:

[image]

I tried to change the font to `NSFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 26)`, then after launch of the application it looks like:

[image]

But after the cell is clicked for the first time, the cell pops smaller again:

[image]

I´m wondering if there is a way to set the backgroundcolor of the whole cell, without becoming smaller after click. I also tried to subclass NSTableHeaderView, but this just draws the whole HeaderView and no more titles could be set. It would be a big help to get some ideas.

EDIT:

According to the suggested answer, I tried to subclass NSTableHeaderCell and set: `tableColumn?.headerCell = MyHeaderCell()`

```
class MyHeaderCell: NSTableHeaderCell {

    override func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
        super.draw(withFrame: cellFrame, in: controlView)
        NSColor.red.set()
        self.backgroundColor = NSColor.red
        NSRectFillUsingOperation(cellFrame, .sourceOver)

    }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

So now the whole HeaderView is colored. By clicking one cell, the cell gets white again. Somehow I still didn´t get it how to change the real background of the cell.

Comment: Why do you replace the header cell in `viewForTableColumn`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply custom styling to NSTableHeaderView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898446/how-to-apply-custom-styling-to-nstableheaderview)

Comment: @Willeke I tried to to perform the suggested solution in your earlier answered question. But I just can´t find out how to do it right. I updated the code with a try of subclassing the Headercell.

Answer (score 0):

## *NSTableViewHeader Background Color*

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var listTableView: NSTableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Set custom header cell class for each table column
    for aColumn in listTableView.tableColumns {
        let customHeaderCell = CustomHeaderCell(textCell: aColumn.headerCell.stringValue)
        customHeaderCell.font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .regular)
        customHeaderCell.textColor = NSColor.white
        aColumn.headerCell = customHeaderCell
    }
 }
}


class CustomHeaderCell: NSTableHeaderCell {

override func draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
    // Draw background color
    NSColor.red.setFill()
    NSBezierPath(rect: cellFrame).fill()
    
    // Draw separator line
    NSColor.lightGray.set()
    NSBezierPath(rect: NSRect(x: cellFrame.origin.x + cellFrame.size.width, y: cellFrame.origin.y, width: 1.0, height: cellFrame.size.height)).fill()
    
    // Draw header text
    let interiorFrame = CGRect(x: cellFrame.origin.x + 4.0, y: cellFrame.origin.y + 6.0, width: cellFrame.size.width, height: 13.0)
    drawInterior(withFrame: interiorFrame, in: controlView)
  }
 }
```

Ref: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpVhx.png